# Clean URI/URL Nginx Rewrite for multiple pages & multiple variables

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am pretty much a moron with regex and I'm just getting started with a cloud-based Nginx server, which is a big change from administering my in-my-closet Apache server.

I'm trying to do rewrites to get clean URLs like this:

```
www.domain.com/folder/red/abc    --->  www.domain.com/folder/red.cfm?query=abc
www.domain.com/folder/blue/ab/cd/ef ---> www.domain.com/folder/blue.cfm?name=ab&city=cd&state=ef
www.domain.com/folder/blue/ab ---> www.domain.com/folder/blue.cfm?name=ab
```

I'm basically trying to get rewrites of items after the "folder" subfolder to rewrite to static .cfm pages. Some of those .cfm pages have zero, one, two or three URL variables; the number of variables is not fixed or consistent.

I have been reading ***A LOT*** about rewrites and try_files, and I have tried, oh, a couple hundred different variations of rewrites, and I just can't seem to find the solution.

For example, I've tried:

```
location /folder/blue {
     rewrite ^/folder/(.*)?$ /folder/blue.cfm?name=$1 last;
      }
```

And this just gets me absolutely nowhere. I would post my entire conf file, but it is *long* due to other stuff that was added in by the default server setup.

I would *love* to make this string as simple as is humanly possible, but I really need help with this. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, it would help having a spec.

It seems like this is the only spec you've provided:

> ```
> www.domain.com/folder/red/abc    --->  www.domain.com/folder/red.cfm?query=abc
> www.domain.com/folder/blue/ab/cd/ef ---> www.domain.com/folder/blue.cfm?name=ab&city=cd&state=ef
> www.domain.com/folder/blue/ab ---> www.domain.com/folder/blue.cfm?name=ab
> ```

The following solution should 100% satisfy the above "spec":

```
location /folder/red/ {
    rewrite ^(/folder/\w+)/(\w*)$ $1.cfm?query=$2 last;
    return 410;
}
location /folder/blue/ {
    rewrite ^(/folder/\w+)/(\w*)$ $1.cfm?query=$2 last;
    rewrite ^(/folder/blue)/(\w*)/(\w*)/(\w*)$ $1.cfm?query=$2&city=$3&state=$4 last;
    return 410;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. I guess I'm not sure how to write a spec for this, but I am wondering how I can have a `/blue/ab/cd/ef` map to a URL with three query variables (blue.cfm?1=ab&2=cd&3=ef), and have `blue/ab/cd` map to a URL with two variables (blue.cfm?1=ab&2=cd), and `blue/ab` map to a one variable URL, etc. Also ... how can I cover a situation in which the trailing slash may or may not be omitted, i.e. `blue/ab` directs the same as `blue/ab/`

I do, sincerely, appreciate the help.

Comment: Just add more `rewrite` directives to cover more cases.  To cover `/folder/blue` without a trailing slash, add a new location on the top level — `location = /folder/blue {return 301 /folder/blue/;}`